# Problema con foreach powershell

Tags: powershell, foreach

Tengo un pequeño problema con un script en powershell... Estoy aprendiendo a programar y no se como resolverlo.

```
$descargas = "C:/Maqueta"

if(Test-Path -Path $descargas -PathType Container){
    Write-Host "El directorio $descargas ya esxiste" -ForegroundColor Yellow
}else{
    Write-Host "Creando directorio $descargas" -ForegroundColor Green
    New-Item -Path $descargas -ItemType directory
}

#Descargar

$lista = ("googlechromestandaloneenterprise64.msi","Winrar.exe")
$Uri =("https://dl.google.com/tag/s/appguid%3D%7B8A69D345-D564-463C-AFF1-A69D9E530F96%7D%26iid%3D%7B03FE9563-80F9-119F-DA3D-72FBBB94BC26%7D%26lang%3Den%26browser%3D4%26usagestats%3D0%26appname%3DGoogle%2520Chrome%26needsadmin%3Dprefers%26ap%3Dx64-stable/dl/chrome/install/googlechromestandaloneenterprise64.msi", 
       "https://www.winrar.es/descargas/103")

$destino = "$descargas"
#Error en los bucles

Foreach($var in $lista){     
   Foreach($var2 in $Uri){
    Invoke-WebRequest $var2 -OutFile $destino\$var

   }
}
```

A la hora de descargar los paquetes indicados Google-Chrome y Winrar me duplica los paquetes al mismo en este caso winrar. El peso de la descarga en un principio es el correcto según el paquete de google chrome pero por algún motivo se vuelve a descargar winrar y sobre escribe el paquete.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es un ejemplo del problema.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y este es el mismo caso, los paquetes se descargan como diferentes pero son los mismo.

Dada  mi poca experiencia en este mundillo que es casi nula no se que hacer...

Comment: Te intentas descargar 4 ficheros, tienes un bucle anidado que hace todas las posibles combinaciones de URLs y ficheros

Comment: Muchas gracias :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como ya te han dicho en los comentarios, al anidar un `foreach` para las uris dentro de un `foreach` para los nombres de los ficheros, estás combinando todos los nombres de fichero con todas las uris. Es decir, al final se están haciendo cuatro llamadas a Invoke-WebRequest equivalentes a:

```
Invoke-WebRequest "https://dl.google.com..." -OutFile $destino\"googlechromestandaloneenterprise64.msi"

Invoke-WebRequest "https://www.winrar.es/descargas/103" -OutFile $destino\"googlechromestandaloneenterprise64.msi"

Invoke-WebRequest "https://dl.google.com..." -OutFile $destino\"Winrar.exe"

Invoke-WebRequest "https://www.winrar.es/descargas/103" -OutFile $destino\"Winrar.exe"
```

Lo que creo que tienes que hacer es crear un array en el que cada elemento tenga la información que necesitas para realizar una descarga, es decir, url y fichero local donde realizar la descarga. Quedaría así:

```
$ficherosADescargar=@();
$ficherosADescargar+= [PSCustomObject] @{
Uri="https://dl.google.com/tag/s/appguid%3D%7B8A69D345-D564-463C-AFF1-A69D9E530F96%7D%26iid%3D%7B03FE9563-80F9-119F-DA3D-72FBBB94BC26%7D%26lang%3Den%26browser%3D4%26usagestats%3D0%26appname%3DGoogle%2520Chrome%26needsadmin%3Dprefers%26ap%3Dx64-stable/dl/chrome/install/googlechromestandaloneenterprise64.msi"
Destino="googlechromestandaloneenterprise64.msi"}

$ficherosADescargar+= [PSCustomObject] @{
Uri="https://www.winrar.es/descargas/103"
Destino="Winrar.exe"}

Foreach($ficheroADescargar in $ficherosADescargar){
    Invoke-WebRequest $($ficheroADescargar.Uri) -OutFile (Join-Path $destino $ficheroADescargar.Destino)
}
```

Como recomendaciones generales:

1. Da nombres descriptivos a las variables. `var`, `var2`, `lista` y `Uri` no son buenos nombres
2. Para componer rutas, utiliza [Join-Path](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/join-path?view=powershell-6)
3. Salvo que estés muy seguro de que el script que estás desarrollando es de *usar y tirar*, usa `Write-Host` solo [cuando realmente sea necesario](http://www.jsnover.com/blog/2013/12/07/write-host-considered-harmful/)

Answer (score 0):

> Esta es la ejecución final del Script

<#         Descarga e instalación
                    Ninja install
    #>

```
<#ROOT#>

param([switch]$elevated)

function Test-Admin {
   $currentUser = New-Object Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal $([Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()) 
   $currentUser.IsInRole([Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltinRole]::Administrator) 
}

if((Test-Admin) -eq $false){
    if($elevated){
        echo "Permisos no concedidos"
    }else{
        Start-Process powershell.exe -Verb RunAs -ArgumentList ('-noprofile -noexit -file "{0}" -elevated' -f ($myinvocation.MyCommand.Definition)) 
    }
    exit
}

echo "Previlegios concedidos"

#Establecemos la ruta de descarga
$descargas = "C:\Dune"

#Primero comprobamos si el directorio existe
#De caso cotrario el directorio se va a crear según la rura establecida
if(Test-Path -Path $descargas -PathType Container){
    Write-Host "El directorio $descargas ya esxiste" -ForegroundColor Yellow
}else{
    Write-Host "Creando directorio $descargas" -ForegroundColor Green
    New-Item -Path $descargas -ItemType directory
}

#Ruta destino "Join-Path", compondremos la ruta
$destino = "$descargas"

#creamos un array en el que cada elemento tenga la información que necesitamos para realizar una descarga.
#Uri y Destino( Ruta de la descarga )
$ficherosADescargar=@();

<#     Inicio elementos array     #>

$ficherosADescargar+= [PSCustomObject] @{
Uri="https://dl.google.com/tag/s/appguid%3D%7B8A69D345-D564-463C-AFF1-A69D9E530F96%7D%26iid%3D%7B03FE9563-80F9-119F-DA3D-72FBBB94BC26%7D%26lang%3Den%26browser%3D4%26usagestats%3D0%26appname%3DGoogle%2520Chrome%26needsadmin%3Dprefers%26ap%3Dx64-stable/dl/chrome/install/googlechromestandaloneenterprise64.msi"
Destino="googlechromestandaloneenterprise64.msi"}


$ficherosADescargar+= [PSCustomObject] @{
Uri="http://rarlab.com/rar/winrar-x64-540.exe"
Destino="Winrar.exe"}

$ficherosADescargar+= [PSCustomObject] @{
Uri="https://download.mozilla.org/?product=firefox-latest-ssl&os=win64&lang=es-ES"
Destino="Firefox.exe"
}

$ficherosADescargar+= [PSCustomObject] @{
Uri="http://descargar.raanmavi.com/adobe-reader-dc-offline"
Destino="AdobeReaderOfflineInstaller.exe"
}

$ficherosADescargar+= [PSCustomObject] @{
Uri="https://fpdownload.macromedia.com/pub/labs/flashruntimes/flashplayer/install_flash_player.exe"
Destino="FlashPlayerChrome.exe"
}

$ficherosADescargar+= [PSCustomObject] @{
Uri="https://fpdownload.macromedia.com/pub/labs/flashruntimes/flashplayer/install_flash_player_ppapi.exe"
Destino="FlashPlayerFirefox.exe"
}


<#     Fin elementos array     #>

#Array de ejecutables .exe .msi
$ejecutables=@()

#Recorremos cada elemento del array
Foreach($ficheroADescargar in $ficherosADescargar){
    #Descarga de ficheros
    Invoke-WebRequest $($ficheroADescargar.Uri) -OutFile (Join-Path $destino $ficheroADescargar.Destino)
    #Instalación de ficheros
    $ejecutables += Join-Path $destino $ficheroADescargar.Destino
}


ForEach($variable in $ejecutables){
   #Argumentos para la instalación
   $MSIargumentos=@(
                 "/i"
                 ('"{0}"' -f $variable)
                 "/passive"
                 "/L*V"
                 "C:\Dune\install.log"
                 )

    #Iniciamos la instalación de los programas
    if($variable -like '*.msi' ){
        Start-Process msiexec.exe -ArgumentList $MSIargumentos -Wait
    }else{
        if( $variable -like "*AdobeReaderOfflineInstaller.exe*"){
            Start-Process -FilePath  ('"{0}"' -f $variable) -ArgumentList "/sAll /rs /rps /msi /norestart /quiet EULA_ACCEPT=YES" -PassThru  -Wait

        }else{
            Start-Process -FilePath  ('"{0}"' -f $variable) -ArgumentList "/S" -PassThru  -Wait
        }
    }
}

remove-item C:\Dune\*.* -Exclude *.log

Write-Host -Fore Green "La instalación ha terminado !!!!!!!"
```